# Reading html from online website C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am reading websites in C# and get contents as string....there are some sites which do not have well formed html structure.

I tried `HtmlAgilityPack` and some others but they need well formed html which is not possible in my case.

Now i need a very simple way to read it by Div or span id/class.

Here is my html http://jsfiddle.net/bwJU7/

please give me a simple C# code which will read

```
div class="item "
```

and get `title` ,`price` ,`photos` and `description` in my html.

Comment: i used HtmlAgilityPack  but it do not work for all sites...please leave HtmlAgilityPack ....its error.count is more than 5000

Comment: Are you sure that HtmlAgilityPack won't do what you want? I've found it pretty tolerant of malformed HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load content as a string and do not expect any regular structure from it then [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) are your friend.

Something like this might help you:

```
String content = "Your content goes here";

var regex = new Regex("<div(?:.*?)class=\"item\"[^>]*>(.*?)</div>");
foreach (Match div in regex.Matches(content))
{               
    Console.WriteLine(div.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Comment: TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ